# iText: how to add a String to a cell

Tags: java, itext, itext7

Hi guys I am an absolute beginner so go easy on me, why is this not working for me, I really do not understand why this is not working, but I am a beginner so if someone could correct this for me, I would really appreciate it.
I am surprised that it does not work

```
import com.itextpdf.kernel.geom.PageSize;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.layout.Document;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Cell;

import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Table;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String path = "C:\\Users\\Kevin\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Generated PDFs\\Table.pdf";
        String logosrc = "C:\\Users\\Kevin\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Generated PDFs\\Images\\mainlogo.png";


        PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(path);
        PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter);
        Document document = new Document(pdfDocument);
        pdfDocument.setDefaultPageSize(PageSize.A4);

        float col = 280f;
        float columnWidth[] = {col, col};
        Table table = new Table(columnWidth);

        table.addCell(new Cell().add("INVOICE"));
```

My Error messege:

```
java: no suitable method found for add(java.lang.String)
    method com.itextpdf.layout.element.Cell.add(com.itextpdf.layout.element.IBlockElement) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; java.lang.String cannot be converted to com.itextpdf.layout.element.IBlockElement)
    method com.itextpdf.layout.element.Cell.add(com.itextpdf.layout.element.Image) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; java.lang.String cannot be converted to com.itextpdf.layout.element.Image)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

iText 7.0 had a method `add(String)` for `Cell`.

For iText 7.1, as [documented in the API](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/java/7.1.15/com/itextpdf/layout/element/Cell.html#add-com.itextpdf.layout.element.IBlockElement-), a `Cell` takes only a *block element* or an *image* for its `add()` method.  [Block elements in iText](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/java/7.1.15/com/itextpdf/layout/element/IBlockElement.html) are things like paragraphs, lists and divs.

You can wrap your `String` in a `Paragraph`:

```java
table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("INVOICE")));
```

For further differences between 7.0 and 7.1, it may be useful to take a look at the [7.1 migration guide](https://kb.itextpdf.com/display/HOME/iText+7.1+-+Migration+guide+for+Java), which also include this change:

> `com.itextpdf.layout.element.Cell#add(java.lang.String)` has been removed, use a `BlockElement` such as `Paragraph` instead.

Comment: Just to add: It looks as if there used to be an `add(String)` method for `Cell` in [earlier versions](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/java/7.0.0/com/itextpdf/layout/element/Cell.html#add-java.lang.String-) of iText 7 - but that has been removed from more recent versions (e.g. [7.1.15](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/java/7.1.15/com/itextpdf/layout/element/Cell.html)). So, maybe the code in the question is from an earlier example/tutorial.

Comment: Fair point. `add(String)` was available in iText 7.0, but was removed in 7.1. I'll add that information to my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much all of you guys i really appreciate the support